# Laravel. How do I fix Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::setBindings() must be of the type array, string given

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I am trying to get the SUM of records within 7 days. but i got the above error

```
$today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$week = jobs::Whereraw('DATEDIFF(?,completed_at) <= 7')
             ->setBindings('[$today]')
             ->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made it a string?

```
    ->setBindings('[$today]')
```

Should be

```
    ->setBindings([$today])
```

No?

Comment: Happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code will be come like below

```
$week = jobs::Whereraw('DATEDIFF(?,completed_at) <= 7')
             ->setBindings([$today])
             ->get();
```

Not string it will `[$today]`